# Get Label value for specified language

Tags: apex, translation, customlabel

I'm trying to implement a preview screen with a picklist of available languages and a textbox with translated text. The problem is **System.Label.My_Preview_Text** or **$Label.My_Preview_Text** are already translated to current User's locale. Is there a way to retrieve a translation for the specified locale, something like **System.Label.getValue('My_Preview_Text','en_US')**. Like we can do this in [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsb0cfet(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)). Is there a way to do that in Apex/VisualForce?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the language for your preview [apex:page](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm). This documentation says that the `language` attribute determines:

> The language used to display labels that have associated translations
>   in Salesforce. This value overrides the language of the user viewing
>   the page. Possible values for this attribute include any language keys
>   for languages supported by Salesforce, for example, "en" or "en-US".

Based on this [unimplemented idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000714WAAQ), it looks like there isn't an Apex API where you can specify the language, so in Apex you always get the current User's language.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is not possible currently in Apex.

This is [already posted on IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000714WAAQ) and you can vote on this idea.

Answer (score 3):

[Summer '23 added such a feature](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_system_label_methods.htm&release=244&type=5):

```
Label.translationExists(namespace, label, language)
Label.get(namespace, label, language)
```

This is based on this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjnjUAB/add-apex-api-for-custom-labels).

Comment: This chould be now the accepted answer.