# Get field translations in apex using integration

Tags: apex, translation

I am using a Partner WSDL and describe calls to get the fields from one salesforce org into other org. The objects and Fields are fetched, however I also want to get the translation for some of the fields.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you get the `label` for the field from a describe call, it will give you the value for the current user's language.

Comment: I am getting it in only one language..I would like to get its English as well as German label

Comment: You would have to set up a separate integration user for each language.

Comment: Ah..is that the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is specific to an integration, I think it is perhaps not a duplicate of: [Get Label value for specified language](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76626/get-label-value-for-specified-language).

The primary difference being: you can set up a distinct integration user for each locale. I believe that is the only way you can do it. As [@KeithC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/887/keith-c) mentions in that post, this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000714WAAQ) seems to indicate there is currently no API to access translations for a dynamically specified language.